# Can a Firebase Storage upload error result in a partial/corrupted file in storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Can a Firebase Storage upload error ever result in a partially-uploaded (or otherwise corrupted) file in cloud storage? Or does any error or inability to return metadata (after an attempted upload) guarantee that nothing was written to storage? I couldn't find anything in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a partial upload will never be committed as an object in a storage bucket.  The upload must finish successfully, or fail completely.  A partial object would cause problems with downstream processing of that object, for example, in Cloud Functions triggers, security rules, or other parts of the system that rely on complete object data.  So that's simply not allowed.